# How to copy all results from a query in Robo3T

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I am using a query to pull a large chunk of fields from a MongoDB database in Robo3T. I want to copy all of the results of my query and paste them into an Excel Spreadsheet. However, when using the table view, Robo3T only lets me copy one value at a time and there is no option to copy when I have multiple values selected.

The only workaround I have found to this solution is to copy the raw JSON data but this is very inefficient as I want to only copy one column of the data. Is there a workaround to copy this data in Robo3T that I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned you need to copy only one column of data you can select which column to get after the find query and get the results as an array.

Eg.
Collection columns: "_id","name","age"
Collection name: "employee"

```
db.getCollection("employee").find({age:20},{name:1})
```

This will return only id and names of the result

If you don't want id to then you need to specify _id:-1

```
db.getCollection("employee").find({age:20},{name:1,_id:-1})
```

If you want to combine all data into a single field (to copy effectively)

```
db.getCollection("employee").find({age:20},{name:1,_id:-1}).toArray()
```